# AppCache Manifest with Grunt add timestamp with Src

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, html5-appcache, offline-caching

I am creating a manifest file for my application. Whenever i do grunt injector task, it will add a timestamp to js and css urls, removing cached files. Now i also need this same url in my manifest files.

My Grunt manifest task:

```
appcache: {
    options: {
        basePath: '<%= global.paths.dist %>/html',
        network: ['http://*', 'https://*'],
        preferOnline: true,
        verbose: true,
        timestamp: true,
        hash: true,
        master: ['index-vendor.html']
    },
    all: {
      dest: '<%= global.paths.dist %>/manifest.appcache',
      cache: {
        patterns: [
          '<%= global.paths.dist %>/**/*', 
          '!<%= global.paths.dist %>/js/bower_components/angular-i18n/**/*'
        ],
        literals: '/'
      }
    }
}
```

My Result looks like:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# rev 1 - 2016-02-16T09:30:49.337Z

CACHE:

index.html
../js/main.js
../styles/css/application.css
../styles/images/loading.gif
../styles/images/logo.svg
../styles/images/progressbar.gif
/

SETTINGS:
prefer-online
```

My Expected Result is:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# rev 1 - 2016-02-16T09:30:49.337Z

CACHE:

index.html
../js/main.js?v=1446033543134
../styles/css/application.css?v=1446033543134
../styles/images/loading.gif?v=1446033543134
../styles/images/logo.svg?v=1446033543134
../styles/images/progressbar.gif?v=1446033543134
/

SETTINGS:
prefer-online
```

Could someone please give me a solution ?